# Amazon Echo Show's background image will not scale

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, echo, show, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to build a skill for the Amazon Echo Show in Python3 to quiz users on U.S. states. In order to do this, I would like to display an image on the Show's screen. However, when I try to do this, my image gets chopped off. I try to scale the image, but this does nothing.

To render the template I use the following code (excuse the empty strings I have as placeholders for the text):

```
'directives': [{
        'type': 'Display.RenderTemplate',
        'template': {
            'type': 'BodyTemplate1',
            'token': 'some sample card',
            'backButton': 'VISIBLE',
            'title': '',
            'backgroundImage': {
                'contentDescription': '',
                'sources': [
                    {
                       'url': 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/94/California_in_United_States.svg',
                       # 'widthPixels': 350,  --> Tried these as well
                       # 'heightPixels': 350,
                       'size': 'SMALL'
                    }
                ]
            },
            'textContent': {
                'primaryText': {
                    'type': 'RichText',
                    'text': ''
                }
            }
        }
    }]
```

I suspect it may have something to do with my template type (BodyTemplate1) or the fact that I am trying to use the backgroundImage for something it isn't supposed to be used for.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by just finding a background image that was 1024px x 600px (the size Amazon specifies for the screen of the Show).